# Image view animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I have a animation assigned to the uiimageview with the following code

```
 Fire.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"firework1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"firework2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"firework3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"firework10.png"],nil];

    [Fire setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    Fire.animationDuration = 0.5;
    [Fire startAnimating];
```

I want the animation to stop when it reaches 0.5 I tried a if statement but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 0.5, is it seconds,, even so  Fire.animationDuration = 0.5; means, that the images within your imageView will animate at a speed of 0.5

Comment: @geet thanks for your help it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/highlightedAnimationImages) documentation setting the animation repeat count to 0 will make it repeat indefinitely, try using `[Fire setAnimationRepeatCount:1];` instead.